# Extract p-value from fisher.test() using pipeline

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Let's have a data set, e.g.:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 50
x <- sample(c(0, 1), replace = TRUE, size = n)
y <- sample(c(1, 2), replace = TRUE, size = n)
```

The task is to create cross-table, compute Fisher's exact test and extract corresponding *p*-value. Here is my pipeline:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gmodels)
tibble(x, y) %>%
  table() %>% 
  CrossTable(prop.r = FALSE, prop.c = FALSE, prop.t = FALSE, prop.chisq = FALSE, fisher = TRUE)
```

which gives the following output:

```
   Cell Contents
|-------------------------|
|                       N |
|-------------------------|


Total Observations in Table:  50 


             | y 
           x |         1 |         2 | Row Total | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
           0 |        15 |        10 |        25 | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
           1 |        13 |        12 |        25 | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
Column Total |        28 |        22 |        50 | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|


Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
------------------------------------------------------------
Sample estimate odds ratio:  1.375572 

Alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
p =  0.7761301 
95% confidence interval:  0.3927115 4.916038 

Alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is less than 1
p =  0.8034681 
95% confidence interval:  0 4.094106 

Alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is greater than 1
p =  0.388065 
95% confidence interval:  0.4686692 Inf 

Any idea how to extract *p*-value ()
```

I need to extract first *p*-value (i.e., 0.7761301). Any idea?

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to use dplyr? This solution seems to work to extract the p-value `fisher.test(x,y)$p.value`

Comment: @Mike I use dplyr pipeline because I filter and summarize data heavily (I just present MWE of the code here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this

```
p <- tibble(x, y) %>%
  table() %>% 
  CrossTable(prop.r = FALSE, prop.c = FALSE, prop.t = FALSE, prop.chisq = FALSE, fisher = TRUE) %>% 
  .$fisher.ts %>% 
  .$p.value

p
[1] 0.7761301
```

Note that you could swap out `.$fisher.ts` for `.$fisher.gt` or `$.fisher.tl`, depending on which one you want.

Comment: It would be `fisher.ts` to get the value the OP wants, `0.776`.

Comment: Thanks. Was actually making that edit as you were commenting!

Answer (score 2):

All you need is

```
a<-tibble(x, y) %>%
  table() %>% 
  CrossTable(prop.r = FALSE, prop.c = FALSE, prop.t = FALSE, prop.chisq = FALSE, fisher = TRUE)

a$fisher.ts$p.value
```